# XSL FO How to prevent retrieve-marker to generate a line break?

Tags: xsl-fo

I used tables to format table captions.

The "retrieve-marker" generates an unwanted line break when table title is short and would be displayed in one line. 
When the title is to long for one line and the line break is generated within the title the "retrieve-marker" generates no line-break.

Is it possible to prevent this line breaks when the table title is short (just a few words)?

It should look like:

```
-------------------------------------
|Table 1   | Picture XYZ (continued)|
-------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Table 1343   | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy|
|             | eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam (continued)   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

It should not look like:
------------------------------
|Table 1   | Picture         | 
|          | XYZ (continued) |
------------------------------
```

My current XSL-FO code:

```
<fo:table table-layout="auto" inline-progression-dimension="auto">
    <fo:table-footer>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:inline white-space-treatment="ignore" keep-together.within-line="always">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$table_title"/>&#160;
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$chapter_number = 0"/>
                            <xsl:when test="$chapter_number = 1">
                                <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="KapitelEbene1" retrieve-position="first-including-carryover" retrieve-boundary="page-sequence"/><xsl:number count="//content/pmentry" level="any" format="1"/><xsl:value-of select="$chapter_number_seperator"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:call-template name="nummerierung_tabelle"/>
                        <xsl:text>&#160;&#160;&#160;</xsl:text>
                    </fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::table/title"/>&#160;<fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="TableContinued" retrieve-position="last-ending-within-page" retrieve-boundary-within-table="page"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-footer>
</fo:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`&#160;` is NO BREAK SPACE.  You are not allowing the formatter to break before the `(continued)`, so it has to drag (at least part of) the preceding word onto the next line when it puts `(continued)` on the next line.

It's not clear to me why the formatter is putting the short caption on two lines, but try specifying the width of the table columns so that the column containing the caption is suitably wide.

Comment: If I specifiy the width of the columns I have to consider the number of the table (e.g. "1" or "200") and different languages (e.g. "Table" or "Tabelle"). There too much alternatives to consider. Thats why I am looking for an easier way to display the caption without havig to much distance between the number and the title fo the table.

Comment: Specify the width just for the second column.  You can specify `width` on the second `fo:table-cell`.  If that is unsupported, you can specify `<fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="..."/>`.  Column widths are required only for the 'fixed' table layout, but it's odd (to me) that `column-width` can't be specified as (or doesn't default to) an `auto` value.

Comment: Specifying `inline-progression-dimension.optimum` on the second `fo:table-cell`  might work better than specifying `width`.  The formatter might be able to increase the width of the column for really long captions.

Comment: You could try setting the width of the first table-cell and right-aligning the table number text: as you have it now, if Table 9 and Table 10 are on the same page, there will be a visible difference in the positions of their captions.

Comment: I tried `<fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="..."/>` and there is no line break anymore. It is not the best solution but I can use it as workaround. Thank you for your fast help :)

Comment: If the answer was useful enough, consider 'accepting' it.